# How to remove dates from position history on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

There used to be a way to remove all dates and months from a position's history and instead say something like "duration: 1 year" instead.

If you try to delete the years currently it prompts for them again before it can submit. If you try to create a new entry it does the same thing. Has anyone found a way to just show number of years employed at each position instead of showing the years?

Comment: I contacted LinkedIn and as of right now it isn't possible. They gave me a link to contact the developers: 
https://www.linkedin.com/lite/feedback-form

Comment: If possible could anyone who is interested in the feature please also submit a request? The more they get the more likely they'll add the feature.